# Why am getting an import error for a package I uploaded to TestPyPi and successfully installed?

Tags: python, package, pypi

This is what my
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZveTh.png) looks like.

This is what my current setup.py looks like:[setup.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIupL.png)

Im currently getting an import error saying the package "windwardrestclient" could not be imported even though its uploaded on TestPyPi (https://test.pypi.org/simple/windwardrestclient/) and i installed it successfully. Im wondering if it is a problem with my setup.py file. How do I setup the setup.py file such that all the files in the the src directory (Api and Model) are included.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't include screenshots of code, it's much easier to debug your issue if you copy/paste your code and/or errors into the question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_packages` tells setuptools which directories to look in for modules.

If you want to be able to `import windwardrestclient`, you need to have a module (a directory with an `__init__.py` file) in one of those directories.

I think the structure you probably want is something like:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── windwardrestclient
        ├── Api
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── Model
        │   └── __init__.py
        └── __init__.py
```

With the following line in `setup.py`:

```py
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed everything. I just got the chance to get back to you but thank you!